# Sonarqube 5.3 integrated security locks system account

Tags: sonarqube

We are having an issue with our sonar service account being locked out by the sonar server, we have enabled DEBUG level logging, and can see sonar is trying to authenticate with the wrong password, I'm not sure where this is coming from but it results in the username account getting locked

"syssonar is not authenticated : The user name or password is incorrect."

We are using Sonar server 5.3, with integrated security for SQL server, and running as a service under windows

```
2016.02.01 15:23:05 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.AdConnectionHelper] Active directory bind string for the domain <dom: LDAP://INTRANET/DC=INTRANET,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=com
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Details for user syssonar: UserDetails{name=sysSonar, email=null, userId=syssonar@INTRANET}
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Authenticating user: syssonar
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] User syssonar is not authenticated : The user name or password is incorrect.
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsUsersProvider] Requesting details for user: syssonar
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Getting details for user: syssonar
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.AdConnectionHelper] Getting active directory bind string for domain: INTRANET
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.AdConnectionHelper] Active directory bind string for the domain INTRANET: LDAP://INTRANET/DC=INTRANET,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=com
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Details for user syssonar: UserDetails{name=sysSonar, email=null, userId=syssonar@INTRANET}
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Authenticating user: syssonar
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] User syssonar is not authenticated : The user name or password is incorrect.
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsUsersProvider] Requesting details for user: syssonar
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.WindowsAuthenticationHelper] Getting details for user: syssonar
2016.02.01 15:23:06 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.AdConnectionHelper] Getting active directory bind string for domain: INTRANET
```

Answer (score 0):

The user who has access rights to the SonarQube SQL Server database must be used to run SonarQube as a service. You have to check the SonarQube connection string if integrated login is enabled

Comment: Yes we use integrated login, and the service user is the dbowner, and this issue is happening only occasionally, most of the time sonar runs fine.